# Upgrading to Django1.8 - invalid related_name for field

Tags: django, django-migrations

I am upgrading my app from Django1.7->Django1.8, but I can't make any changes or even run migrations because I keep seeing the following system error whenever I attempt to perform any migration operation in the 1.8 environment

```
ERRORS:
content.Content.polymorphic_ctype: (fields.E306) The name 'polymorphic_content.content_set' is invalid related_name for field Content.polymorphic_ctype
    HINT: Related name must be a valid Python identifier or end with a '+'
content.Tag.polymorphic_ctype: (fields.E306) The name            'polymorphic_content.tag_set' is invalid related_name for field Tag.polymorphic_ctype
    HINT: Related name must be a valid Python identifier or end with a '+'
promotion.PZoneOperation.polymorphic_ctype: (fields.E306) The name 'polymorphic_promotion.pzoneoperation_set' is invalid related_name for field     PZoneOperation.polymorphic_ctype
    HINT: Related name must be a valid Python identifier or end with a '+'
reviews.MediaItem.polymorphic_ctype: (fields.E306) The name    'polymorphic_reviews.mediaitem_set' is invalid related_name for field   MediaItem.polymorphic_ctype
    HINT: Related name must be a valid Python identifier or end with a '+'
```

The problem is that 3 of those apps are part of a dependency and have already updated the `related_name` of the 3 fields to end with `+` in the `0001_initial.py` migration, but I can't revert backwards due to the system errors. Kind of at loss with how to proceed with updating.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting and re-generating your migrations with `manage.py makemigrations <appname>` for each app.

Answer (score 0):

I had troubles with migrations after upgrading too. If wiping your whole DB and repopulating it from a scratch is an option, try this (after cleaning the DB):
1) run `./manage.py makemigrations app_name` for each app
2) run `./manage.py migrate`
3) run `./manage.py syncdb`